# How to use gstreamer for transcoding and resizing from mp4(h264/aac) to mp4(h264/mp3)?

Tags: gstreamer, mp4, h.264, aac, gst-launch

I want to transcode and resize mp4.(mp4-h264_1920x1080/aac => mp4-h264_640x480/mp3) using gstreamer. I wrote down this command.

```
$ gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=./gain_1.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux demux.video_00 ! queue ! ffdec_h264 ! videoscale ! 'video/x-raw-yuv,width=640,height=480' ! x264enc ! queue ! qtmux name=mux mux.video_0 demux.audio_00 ! queue ! ffdec_aac ! lame bitrate=128 ! queue ! mux.audio_0 mux. ! filesink location=0000.mp4 –v -e
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Redistribute latency...
^CCaught interrupt -- handling interrupt.
Interrupt: Stopping pipeline ...

(gst-launch-0.10:17958): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 1 was not found when attempting to remove it
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

which didn't work.

Transcoding video-only works :

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=./gain_1.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux demux.video_00 ! queue ! ffdec_h264 ! videoscale ! 'video/x-raw-yuv, width=640, height=480' ! x264enc ! queue ! mux. mp4mux name=mux ! filesink location=0000.mp4 –v -e
```

And transcoding audio-only too:

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=./gain_1.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux demux.audio_00 ! ffdec_aac ! lame bitrate=128 ! queue ! mux. mp4mux name=mux ! filesink location=0000.mp4 –v -e
```

How can I transcode audio and video with the same command?

Comment: What was your exact issue with the first command?

Comment: @Mathieu_Du The message is next when I was made to run that command. =>

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Redistribute latency...

And just ended.

Comment: Try to put a queue right after the demuxer's audio pad, before ffdec_aac maybe ?

Comment: @Mathieu_Du I was try to put a queue. like this ~~~ x264enc ! queue ! mux. demux.audio_00 ! queue ! ffdec_aac ! lame ~~~~ But, result is same.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what happens there, you should try this with gstreamer 1.0, and if you still reproduce come discuss that on the gtsreamer IRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh~
I solved this problem.
Next command did good work.

```
gst-launch-0.10 ffmux_mp4 name=mux ! \
filesink location=0000.mp4 \
filesrc location=./gain_1.mp4 ! qtdemux name=vdemux vdemux.video_00 ! queue ! ffdec_h264 ! videoscale ! 'video/x-raw-yuv, width=640, height=480' ! x264enc ! queue ! mux. \
filesrc location=./gain_1.mp4 ! qtdemux name=ademux ademux.audio_00 ! ffdec_aac ! lame bitrate=128 ! queue ! mux.`
```

Answer (score 2):

@Lionel.J I would like to suggest two improvements:

1. if possible, use gstreamer-1
2. your solution reads the source file twice. That's not necessary. Furthermore, the audio and video streams are not synchronized when you do this. You can read both audio and video streams out of qtdemux.

This is a pipeline which does the job with gstreamer-1 and reads the source only once:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e filesrc location=/path/to/big_buck_bunny_720p_h264.mov ! \
decodebin name=decode ! \
videoscale ! 'video/x-raw,width=640,height=480' ! \
x264enc ! queue ! mp4mux name=mp4mux ! filesink location=0000.mp4 \
decode. ! audioconvert ! lamemp3enc bitrate=128 ! queue ! mp4mux.
```

Comment: It gives me: (gst-launch-1.0:5692): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_make_from_uri: assertion 'gst_uri_is_valid (uri)' failed
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: syntax error

Comment: @mabg The pipeline should work as shown. Maybe you are missing a plugin. Try running with `-v` to find out what happen. `export GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR=/tmp` before running the pipeline will cause gst-launch to dump the pipeline at various times. That could help too. To convert the dump to a picture, run `dot -Tpng -o pipeline.png /tmp/one-of-the-files.dot`.

Comment: The problem are the ' of video/x-rax,width=... If put it without ', it seems it works, because appears another problem, no element "x264enc", but nothing about syntax error

Comment: x264enc is part of GStreamer Ugly Plugins. May be you need to install that separately (Package gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly on Debian-like Linuxes).